# My styles.css file isn't being applied to a dynamic route in a node.js application

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a simple blog-style application using express and ejs for views. I was able to successfully render my home, about, contact, etc, but when I attempted to render a posts/:index page the css was not applying. Here is the code from my app.js...

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const posts = [
  {
    title: "Barbarian",
    content: "Barbarian is one of the better horror films in recent memory."
  }
];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
app.use('/posts/:index', express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is running on port 3000');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { posts: posts } );
});

app.get('/posts/:index', (req, res) => {
  res.render('post', {});
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact', {});
});

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', {});
});

app.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('new', {});
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let post = {};
  post.title = req.body.blogTitle;
  post.content = req.body.blogContent;
  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

I was expecting the posts/:index page to render with CSS from my styles.css. To be clear, I initially only had this code to handle serving static files.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
```

After some research, I attempted adding this...

```
app.use('/posts/:index', express.static(__dirname + '/public/styles'));
```

Answer (score 0):

### **1. Add this middleware in the `index.js` above you set view engine**

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

### **2. Folder Structure**

```
|__public/   
    |__ css/
        |__ css files...
    |__ js/
        |__ js files...
```

**3. Import this way**

Now you set the path to the public directory you have to give the path public folder when you import

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
```

## **You should now be all set up to access css or any file**